# Prometheus not getting metrics in snapshots

Tags: linux, prometheus, metrics, snapshot

I want to export data from prometheus and import to another one.
Found three posts and all of them said just put snapshots to the new one under storage.tsdb.path/snapshots and it's okay.

However I can't reproduce it. It seems Prometheus never acknowledge my copied snapshots in logs (see my last section), but I don't know why and I found nothing related to this issue...

Please let me know what I was missing... It seems like an easy thing but I can't figure it out.

I also asked this question in [Prometheus User Group](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/OdmyNSnX594/m/naSE4JUbBQAJ) but no one replied to it yet.

Reference posts

1. https://www.robustperception.io/taking-snapshots-of-prometheus-data

   > This post said pointing storage.tsdb.path to snapshots directory would work, I tried but it didn't work.
2. https://devopstales.github.io/home/backup-and-retore-prometheus/
3. https://suraj.io/post/how-to-backup-and-restore-prometheus/

### What did I do

I use docker and do the following steps.

1. Run prometheus container with `--web.enable-admin-api`
2. Snapshot by api $curl -XPOST http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/snapshot
3. Using docker cp to copy snapshots. And checked the directory size which is ~250M.
   $ du -sh snapshots
   250M    snapshots

I tried 2 ways to import data

1. Copy to another prometheus container.
2. Copy snapshots to /data/snapshots and mount /data to prometheus'  storage.tsdb.path.
   Note: /data is empty except snapshots directory.

My tests were done on 2021/4/22 and my data is around 2021/4/16. All of the containers' retention time is default 15 days.

### What I expect to see

I use Grafana's "explore" function to check metric "up" and try to see data on 4/16, but nothing shows.

### What did you see instead? Under which circumstances?

Containers of both way 1 and way 2 show only metrics when they start on 2021/4/22, but there are no metrics on 2021/4/16.

### Environment

- System information:

My host is a vmware player 16 virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04

Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64

- Prometheus version:

I'm using the container version of Prometheus.
prometheus, version 2.25.2 (branch: HEAD, revision: bda05a23ada314a0b9806a362da39b7a1a4e04c3)
build user:       root@de38ec01ef10
build date:       20210316-18:07:52
go version:       go1.15.10
platform:         linux/amd64

- Prometheus configuration file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'monitor'

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - alertmanager:9093

rule_files:
  - "/prom_setup/alert.rules"
  # - "second.rules"
 
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 192.168.41.164:9090

  - job_name: 'host_A'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.41.164:9100']

  - job_name: 'container_A'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']
```

- docker-compose file:

```
    prometheus:
        container_name: promethues
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

           # try to mount only snapshots to prometheus
            - ./prom_data/:/prometheus/data/
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
            - '--web.enable-lifecycle'

              # to enable snapshot  
            - '--web.enable-admin-api'
```

### File permissions on host

- data directory

`drwxrwxrwx  5 lou  lou  4096 Apr 22 08:28 prom_data/`

- snapshots directory

`drwxrwxrwx  4 lou    lou      4096 Apr 22 08:28 snapshots/`

```
$ du -sh snapshots
250M    snapshots
```

- Logs:

```
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.992Z caller=main.go:366 msg="No time or size retention was set so using the default time retention" duration=15d
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.993Z caller=main.go:404 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.25.2, branch=HEAD, revision=bda05a23ada314a0b9806a362da39b7a1a4e04c3)"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.993Z caller=main.go:409 build_context="(go=go1.15.10, user=root@de38ec01ef10, date=20210316-18:07:52)"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.993Z caller=main.go:410 host_details="(Linux 5.4.0-70-generic #78~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 14:10:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 8fa848a981f9 (none))"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.993Z caller=main.go:411 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.993Z caller=main.go:412 vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:20.998Z caller=web.go:532 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.003Z caller=main.go:779 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.008Z caller=head.go:668 component=tsdb msg="Replaying on-disk memory mappable chunks if any"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.008Z caller=head.go:682 component=tsdb msg="On-disk memory mappable chunks replay completed" duration=4.448µs
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.008Z caller=head.go:688 component=tsdb msg="Replaying WAL, this may take a while"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.008Z caller=head.go:740 component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=0 maxSegment=0
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.008Z caller=head.go:745 component=tsdb msg="WAL replay completed" checkpoint_replay_duration=24.518µs wal_replay_duration=292.774µs total_replay_duration=360.306µs
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.009Z caller=tls_config.go:191 component=web msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.009Z caller=main.go:799 fs_type=EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.010Z caller=main.go:802 msg="TSDB started"
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.010Z caller=main.go:928 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.011Z caller=main.go:959 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=1.487753ms remote_storage=2.162µs web_handler=883ns query_engine=1.467µs scrape=420.502µs scrape_sd=113.37µs notify=17.922µs notify_sd=28.211µs rules=550.056µs
promethues      | level=info ts=2021-04-22T00:28:21.011Z caller=main.go:751 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
```

Comment: Any luck? I am having pretty much the same issue?

Comment: @dcg Sorry, no. I also tested on Kubuntu 14.04 and no luck..

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had the same issue. It was my mistake - and it's true, the documentation is not 100% clear either.

So, I had the snapshot stored in a directory like `{DATA}\{XXXX-XXXX}\{YYYY}`. My mistake was I was copying the content of directory `{XXXX-XXXX}\{YYYY}`. I should have copied the content of directory `{XXXX-XXXX}`. Did that and it works.

If you check the storage documentation (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/) you will understand.

Comment: Did you copied `data/snapshot` or all directories under `data`? I tried prior one but it didn't work.

Comment: So, you have `/data/snapshots/AAA-BBB/CCC`. It seems like the snapshot is actually all the files and subdirectories under `/data/snapshots/AAA-BBB`. This is what you have to move from one place to another. All CCC directories (and files) must be copied from `snapshots` to the `/data` of the new Prometheus. Also, wait like 5 mins. Not sure why, but that worked for me.